# Python/Pandas: Identify value count in a series and report. Also report "nan" counts

Tags: python, pandas, series

In the following code I would like to count the number of times a particular value occurs in "Value" column and report it in column "Count_Non_Null".  Similarly I will like to count how many times null (np.nan) appear and report in column "Count_Nulls".

In the example below the value "NFLX" appears once, "FB" appears 2 times, "MSFT" appears 3 times etc.  Also np.nan appears 4 times.

The intent is to generate output similar to what's given in the image.[Image of how the report is expected to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpvpS.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={ 
      'Value': [
                   'NFLX','FB','GOOG','VZ',np.nan,'MSFT','AMZN'
                   ,np.nan,'MSFT',np.nan,'MSFT','INTC','AAPL'
                   ,np.nan,'AMZN','FB'
               ]
     }

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Value'])

df['Count_Non_Null'] = False
df['Count_Nulls'] = False

print (df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `transform` with `size` to get the counts of non-nan values, and then sum up the nans, assigning them with `loc` to the nan rows.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = { 
    'Value': [
        'NFLX','FB','GOOG','VZ',np.nan,'MSFT','AMZN',
        np.nan,'MSFT',np.nan,'MSFT','INTC','AAPL',
        np.nan,'AMZN','FB'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) # no need for 'columns' argument
```

**Calling transform with size and adding up NaNs**

```
df = df.assign(
    Count_Non_Null=df.groupby('Value')['Value'].transform('size'), # call .fillna(False) here if you need it
    Count_Nulls=np.nan # You can also use False here
)

df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Value']), 'Count_Nulls'] = pd.isnull(df['Value']).sum()
```

**Result**

```
>>> df
   Value  Count_Non_Null  Count_Nulls
0   NFLX             1.0          NaN
1     FB             2.0          NaN
2   GOOG             1.0          NaN
3     VZ             1.0          NaN
4    NaN             NaN          4.0
5   MSFT             3.0          NaN
6   AMZN             2.0          NaN
7    NaN             NaN          4.0
8   MSFT             3.0          NaN
9    NaN             NaN          4.0
10  MSFT             3.0          NaN
11  INTC             1.0          NaN
12  AAPL             1.0          NaN
13   NaN             NaN          4.0
14  AMZN             2.0          NaN
15    FB             2.0          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas !! The solution given by you produces the expected result.